# Fish shell: Map jk to enter normal mode (in vi mode)

Tags: vi, fish

While using vi keybindings in fish shell, is it possible to map jk to enter Normal mode? Currently Escape is used for doing that but I want to change (or add a new way) to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
bind --mode insert --sets-mode default jk repaint
```

This adds a key binding when in insert mode, which switches the mode to default. The key sequence of the binding is `jk`, and its command is to repaint. (The repainting is necessary if your prompt shows the current mode, which it does by default.)